# Borescope recommendations (features)

Tags: tools, wiring

I'd love to get a [borescope](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borescope), but I've never used one. Should I try to find a place to rent one first (does such a place even exist?) or should I bite the bullet and buy one? What features should I be looking for?

Specifically, I want one to be able to examine inside walls in preparation for running wire, (i.e., Cat 6, coax, ROMEX).

Comment: Here's a [list of companies](http://www.thomasnet.com/products/borescope-rental-7003122-1.html) that rent them.  Sorry, can't help you with the feature list.

Comment: If you live in the US you could check to see if Lowe's or Home Depot's rental departments have them (I don't know).

Comment: Note that any future answers that are product recommendations will be removed per the community on topic policy.

Comment: Highly recommend one.  I don't use mine a lot (from HD), but when I do it's been invaluable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This one](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000WTKC3O) has really good reviews on Amazon, for what it's worth.  It comes with 3 attachments: a hook, a mirror, and a magnet, all of which sound like nice things to have.  There are also extension cables available for going longer distances inside the wall (the included cable is 3 feet).  Here's a pic:
[image: borescope]

The price seems really reasonable at $160 (as of Nov. 2010).  My guess is that if you went to rent one, you'd be limited to more commercial-grade models and that if you wanted to keep it for a few days you'd be looking at something close to that just in rental charges.

Comment: I've seen this (or similar models) for around $100 on sale.   It would be hard to justify paying for a rental unit at that price point.

Answer (score 0):

Harbor Freight has one for US$159.99 (right now it's on sale for $119.99). It's in-store only, but here is the [page on their site](http://www.harborfreight.com/wireless-inspection-camera-with-24-inch-color-lcd-monitor-66550.html). I don't have any experience with it so I can't make a recommendation.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

http://www.usbfever.com/index_eproduct_view.php?products_id=965

$60 - plug it into a laptop - can take pictures

I never run wires without using this first

Comment: $49 on Jan 16, 2014. Claims USB 1.1.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need a semi-rigid cable, Teslong makes an [inexpensive USB borescope](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07D8RYFCD) with a 50' cable ($28). I've used this with my laptop to examine my HVAC system, and it is apparently compatible with most smartphones (although I haven't had any luck finding a USB adapter that fits my Google Pixel).

[image: Teslong 1200P 50' USB borescope]