# Secure TV mount?

Tags: mounting, studs, television

I'm not much of a DIYer, but I was thinking about mounting 2 or 3 TVs (not all mine, some my parents' etc), 32", 40" and 50".

Obviously I'll be getting a stud finder and using that to find studs. The mount will be something like this: [TygerClaw Tilting Flat-Panel TV Wall Mount](http://www.walmart.ca/en/ip/tygerclaw-37-63-tilting-flat-panel-tv-wall-mount-lcd3401blk/6000037600983)

If I use 2 studs to mount the TV, how secure is this? Is there a chance the TV will fall? What are things to watch out for?

Comment: The studs are behind drywall, don't know the width of the drywall.

Comment: btw my 32 inch tv is pretty old lcd (had for at least 5 years), would it be mountable? Some GE Westinghouse model

Comment: @pkamb If you find PII in a post, please flag it for moderator attention so it can be redacted properly. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

**Short answer:** As long as you're compliant with the TV/mounting documentation and there aren't significant defects in the studs (e.g. termite damage, water damage, etc) you should be fine.

**Longer answer:** I did this fairly recently and my advice is as follows...

- Make sure you purchase a TV stand that is rated for the size/weight of your TV.  The specs on the site look pretty beefy but don't take any chances.  Consult your TV manual for mounting details.  Most (if not all) TV manuals will explicitly specify the weight of the TV and what VESA mounting pattern is required.
- Confirm what's included in the mounting kit and what surfaces it's rated for.  The mount should explicitly say what its rated for and what's required.  Our mounting kit (different brand) came with two sets of screws (1 set for concrete and 1 set for wood).
- Get a mounting kit that supports heavier weights and multiple VESA patterns. If/when you ever upgrade the TV, you don't want to have to replace it. :-)
- Have a friend help.  Installation is waaaaaaaaaaaayyyyy easier (and much safer) when multiple people are involved.
- Check to see if the mounting kit lets you make small adjustments AFTER it's mounted.  After setting (and re-setting) our TV mount several times, I later learned that it had the ability to make slight tilt modifications while mounted. D'oh! This saves gobs of time and is an awesome feature.

Lastly, check out these posts here for other insightful info:

[What's the least intrusive way to find out what's in a wall?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/3256/whats-the-least-intrusive-way-to-find-out-whats-in-a-wall)

[How do I run wires for a wall-mount flatscreen TV?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/742/how-do-i-run-wires-for-a-wall-mount-flatscreen-tv)

Answer (score 0):

TVs can be mounted to walls.  I have two of them mounted on articulating arms.

There are two points of concern:

1. TV to Mount
2. Mount to Wall

From TV to Mount ensure that:

- Mount can be bolted to TV

There are standard patterns (VESA) and bolt sizes that most TVs support.  The mounting hardware should provide a bunch of different options (screws/bolts and mount points).  Ensure that the connection between the TV and the mount is secure.  If not, you may have to return the mount and get another one  (this happened to me).  In my case, the mounting pattern was OK, but the bolts did not work out, so I had to use a different model.  The mounting pattern between the TV and mount must be capatible as well as the bolt or screws must be compatible (size and length).  Usually the TV documentation will state what is supports as far a mounts and screw sizes.  Older TVs may be problematic.  This area wasn't as standardized in the early days (and has changed a few times) so definately check your TV model # for appropriate bolting pattern and bolt/screw sizes.

Ensure that mount can support TV weight.  I can say that most TVs are getting lighter.  I have a 125 lb mount supporting a 50" plasma and a 25 lb mount supporting a 42" LED.  The LED TV weighs < 20 lbs.

Take into account the TV height and width prior to mounting so that it is centered on the wall and at an enjoyable viewing height.  Also, some mounts cost more money but have more features like swiveling, tilting, extend and/or retract.

From Mount to Wall ensure that:

- Mount must be secured to studs or other solid infrastructure.

Usually the mount will come with some sort of lag bolts which will be used to attach the mount to the wall.  Do not substitute hardware.  Use a stud finder, do not guess.  A solid connection will mean that the lag bolt will require some force to secure it.  Do not over tighten.  If the lag bolt is going in easily or with little effort I would be concerned that it isn't attached to secure infrastructure like a stud.

Consider adding an electrical box and cable outlet behind the tv as well.  Otherwise, you will have a bunch of wires dangling from TV to floor.  One can buy covers to hide the wires, but long term the connections would be better served behind the TV for clean installation.