# Process in installing a TV

Tags: drywall, mounting, television

New first time buyer here! Finally got the keys to the new house! Exciting times! Will be going into it pretty soon!

I bought a Samsung Frame TV 55” for it. I do plan on hanging the tv on the wall. I haven’t done much DIY project and was watching this YouTube video:

https://youtu.be/bdQPmYCD-vk

I’ve got a few questions:
1 - I was looking at few tv mounting advice and I saw someone say you shouldn’t hang a TV solely on drywall? It should also be on a stud. Is this correct?

2 - in the vid did he drill everything on a stud? I watched it several times but don’t seem to catch whether or not he drilled through the stud for the toggle bolts.

3 - which size toggle bolts should I get? He drilled the hole with a .5” bit. Am I right in assuming I can use any bolts?

4 - other than using a stud finder, how do I make sure I don’t drill through a pip or something? And how far do I drill through a stud? (This probably sounds pretty stupid but I just wanna make sure)

Comment: Welcome to [diy.se]. If you'll take a look at the "how to ask" section of the [help], you'll see that we like to focus on one question at a time here, and that you've asked quite a number of questions all in one. We also prefer not to answer the same question over and over, so please use the search for key words like "stud finder" and "TV mount" and you'll find plenty of answers about how to use a stud finder and recommendations for installing TV mounts. If you still have questions after reading several of those, please feel free to [edit] your post to ask about your specific concern.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Secure TV mount?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/37203/secure-tv-mount)

Answer (score 3):

The bracket should be screwed into at least one stud and preferably two. Drywall just doesn't provide the support for a large TV.
In the video, the center holes were screwed into the stud and the two end toggle bolts went in the drywall.
The bolt sizes will depend on the bracket you buy. In many instances, the bolts and screws will be provided. If they are not, the instructions will specify what you need.
There isn't really a good way to check behind  walls without a stud finder. You can push a long finishing nail into the drywall a number of times to determine the stud locations and move the nail around in the holes to "see" if you feel any wires or pipes. Since you're a homeowner, you'll be doing a lot of picture hanging,etc. so you'd be smart to get a good stud finder.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, don't be afraid to read the instructions. Your TV mounting bracket definitely comes with them. If you do read them and still don't understand, don't be afraid to get help.
Now, for the specific questions.

1. Do not trust the drywall to hold the full load of a large TV on a  small mounting area. The instructions will tell you this too.
2. You can't use a toggle bolt in a stud. The toggle is the part that moves freely in the empty cavity in the wall. It just won't work otherwise.
3. No, you can't use just any toggle bolts, but you have plenty of options. You want a bolt small enough to fit through the bracket, but big enough to be secure. The instructions will give recommendations regarding size. Look up different styles of toggle bolts and anchors, and learn about what each is good for.
4. A stud finder will never see a pipe. If you're drilling in drywall, just stop as soon as you break through. If you're drilling in a stud, you don't have to worry about anything being closer than an inch from the edge of the stud. If there's a wire or pipe closer than that, it will probably be protected with a metal plate on the stud. Structurally, you can drill as deep as you want without compromising the strength.

Good luck.

Comment: "don't be afraid to read the instructions." What a novel concept! I may have to try that! `</sarcasm>` if only people would do that, we'd have 1/2 the questions here...